# Increment a field through with the set() method in batch operations in Android Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection which holds documents that has only a single field named "likeCount". I want to increment this when someone hits the like button from my android app. The thing is, when a post is liked for the first time, I want to create a new document for that post. If it has already been liked, a simple increment would be enough. 
Adding to this, I am performing this through a batch operation as I have to update another collection as I am doing this

In my corresponding iOS app I wrote the following code to get this done:

```
batch.setData(
[WallPostPublicFields.likeCount.rawValue: FieldValue.increment(1)], 
forDocument: referance(to:.wall_post_public).document(postId),
merge: true
)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do the same in kotlin? Because in kotlin's batch.set() method takes only a doc reference, data and set Options as arguments.

I am new to kotlin and Android development so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin, simply use the following lines of code:

```
val batch = db.batch()
val postId = db.collection("posts").document().id
val postIdRef = db.collection("posts").document(postId) 
batch.set(postIdRef, "likeCount", 0);
batch.update(postIdRef, "likeCount", FieldValue.increment(1))
batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener {
    //Your logic
}
```

If the `likeCount` does not exist, it will be created at the first like.

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you so much for answering, but I think you misunderstood my question, I want to create a **document** when it is liked for the first time. If it was just a new field, this would do the trick. But when there isn't a document, the update method doesn't work.

Comment: In this tcase, you need to add the creation of the document first to the batch, as seen in my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you again so much for helping out. I didn't get back to the project until today. In your updated answer, you are declaring the postId when this function is called right? In my case, I get the postId as an argument from the UI component when the post like is clicked.

Comment: "you are declaring the postId when this function is called right?" Yes, I'm getting the `postId` once the `document()` function is called. This is how you generate that unique id in Firestore. "I get the postId as an argument from the UI component" This is even easier, instead of generating that id, use the one from the UI when you are setting `postIdRef` like so `val postIdRef = db.collection("posts").document(postIdFromUi)`.